# How to test SQL scripts? (Data Integrity/Migration Testing)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, testing, data-migration, data-integrity

Our team (QA) is facing the following problem:

We have a database that is accessed only by our `Core` application which is a `WCF services` app. Our client applications are using the `Core` to access the database.

At some point we were provided with a new Version of our `Core application` and of our `Database`. The `Dev` department also gave us a sql script which is altering a big part of our `database Core data`. The `core data` are used by the `Core Application` to describe the Logic of our system, so every change on that data may have affects on any of our client application's functionality.

My questions are:

- Should we test all of our applications again (even if they are
  already fully tested) or is there is a more efficient way to test the
  SQL script?
- **Is there a testing technique/tool for data integrity/migration testing?**

---

I am looking for a quick validity/integrity testing of the database  after running a migration script. That will prevent us losing time by testing it through the applications. If the validity/integrity testing is successful then we can test the apps.

Comment: I would absolutely test the application. Testing the script could show errors in the conversion process, etc. However, it won't necessarily show errors in the way data is accessed via the service or consumed by the client applications.

Comment: @Tim Lentine Thank you for your answer. I was just looking for something that could confirm me that the databases updates were correct not just successful (without errors) so I will not need to fully test the applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description you gave:

> We have a database that is accessed only by our Core application ...
>   we were provided with a new Version of our Core application and of
>   our Database ...

tells me it is not your team's responsibility to test the database in isolation, but you *can* test the Core service from your client's perspective and therefore assume the database is correct.

Treat the Core application *and* the database as a [black box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) and test using Unit Tests. These test should not require you to go poking around in the database as for all intents and purposes any application using your Core application doesn't know, nor should care, that the information is actually stored in to a database. You development team could decide in 6 months they are going to store the data in the Cloud in which case all your database test will be broken.

If you *do* have to look in the database to check data has been stored correctly then there is a problem with your Core service's interface as any data you put in should be retrievable via the same interface (I just know someone is going to comment that their app does store data which cannot be read back but without a more detailed description of your app it's easier to generalise).

Back in the real world I am assuming you are part of the QA team and unless the database developers are doing some testing (they are, aren't they?) you are more than likely going to have to validate the database changes.

To the end you may be interested to read a question I posted on the DBA Stack Exchage site about [performing a data comparison between two different schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/are-there-tools-to-perform-data-comparison-between-two-different-schemas). Spoiler: there's no easy answer.

Comment: I am 100% agreed with everything you said. However, as you said, in the real world things are a bit more complicated. The black box testing of the Core application would not shows us any problem because it's functionality was not changed. New data will be added to db correctly. The problems could be occur on the existent data.

Comment: In which case you have two separate issues; the first being is able to verify the database has the same data in it as it did before the "upgrade", and second that the client applications will not be broken by the changes. For the first you will have to do the type of comparison I described in my dba.stackexchange question; the second issue means that yes, you will have to test all your applications again (as you should when *anything* changes). Regression testing should not be an onerous task if you have your tests automated.

Comment: Your question to dba.stackexchange is indeed very helpful, many good answers, with yours as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are unit testing frameworks available for T-SQL. The [TSQLUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) project is one such framework. You can use it to set up automated testing, just like you would in the applications.

Comment: Thanks, I just start reading about it and it seems quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

as @Tim Lentine already posted, I would recomend testing the full application. As you commented, the new sql script your team received has made important changes on the core of your database development, according to your description, both on the structure and the data itself. So in order to be sure that everything is still on one piece I would preferably do a full application test. As for a tool or technique I can recomend the new RedGate  (no, I do not work for them) addon on the SSMS called "SQL Test". It uses the unit testing [open source tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/) for its purposes. It only has the drawback that someone will need to first learn how to work with tSQLt but is prettu straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check your suggestion for the RedGate tool. As for the applications' testing is not that we will not test them but it will be quite efficient for a quick test on the updates from the sql script and then to start testing the applications. Just think the waste of time if you are testing 6-7 applications and after a week you find an error on the script.

Answer (score 1):

show below links :

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-unit-testing-with-tsqlt/

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/

Comment: Thanks, the first link was really helpful.